# Determining Whether a function is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm positive this function is linear but am having trouble showing it:

Determine whether $T:V \to W$ defines a linear transformation:

$V=R^3$, $W=R$

$T((a_1, a_2, a_3)) = 3a_1 +2a_2 + a_3 $

I know I have to show that $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$ and $T(cu) = cT(u)$ but am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps you should take to prove $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$.

1. Set $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$.
2. Write down what $T(u)$ is.
3. Write down what $T(v)$ is.
4. Write down what $T(u)+T(v)$ is.
5. Write down what $u+v$ is.
6. Write down what $T(u+v)$ is.
7. Compare results from (3) and (5).

Which of these steps were you able to do, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I got it! Thanks for laying out the steps for me like that, it worked out very nicely. I also did T(cu) = cT(u) to show that it is closed under scalar multiplication!

Comment: @Mathstatsstudent Happy to help. Remember, if you don't know what do do, always go back to the definitions and split the problem into small steps.